# Trying to append variable to json returns an error in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Disclaimer: The majority of this might not make sense, as basically all of this is just me trying to do something I have never done before.

I am trying to make a discord bot that has a "leaderboard" type system. But what I tried, gave me an error.

Heres my code.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
from json import loads
import os
TOKEN = 'Token'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as: {bot.user.name}')
    print(f'With ID: {bot.user.id}')


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    if message.channel.id == 782989981752098886:
        if message.author == bot.user:
            return
        else:

            if ''.join(message.content.split()).lower() == "egg":
                os.chdir(r'Directory')
                with open('EggData.json', 'r') as file:
                    data = loads(file.read())
                try:
                    author = message.author.mention
                    usernameList = data
                    authorsAmount = usernameList[author]
                    print(authorsAmount)
                    usernameList[author] += 1
                    print(usernameList[author])
                    print(usernameList)
                    with open('EggData.json', 'w') as outfile:
                        json.dump(usernameList, outfile)
                    return
                except:
                    addUsersID = {f"{author}" : 0}
                    appendUserID = usernameList.append(addUsersID)
                    with open('EggData.json', 'w') as outfile:
                        json.dump(appendUserID, outfile)
                    author = message.author.mention
                    usernameList = data
                    authorsAmount = usernameList[author]
                    print(authorsAmount)
                    usernameList[author] += 1
                    print(usernameList[author])
                    print(usernameList)
                    with open('EggData.json', 'w') as outfile:
                        json.dump(usernameList, outfile)
                    return
                return
            else:
                await message.channel.send(
                    "{} You fool. You absolute buffoon, it is illegal to say anything other than 'egg' in this server. I hope you feel the shame in side you. Us only saying 'egg' in this channel brings peace to our server, and you thinking your above everyone? above ME? You {}, have messed up. I want you to take a long time to reflect your self.".format(message.author.mention, message.author.mention))
    else:
        return

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

It works just fine if I manually add the users ID and remove the `try:` and `except:`. But with the part that has the `try:` and `except:` is the part I tried to do in order to add the user to the list if they aren't already on it.
Here is what the json looks like:
`{"<@494664629570764810>": 11, "variblePlaceholder": 4, "numbernumbernumberPlaceholder": 26}`
I will try to answer any questions you may have, as I am sure this isn't very clear.

### EDIT:

Forgot to say the error. The error I'm getting is
`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

### TRACEBACK ERROR:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\name\Desktop\Python\ProofOfConcept\JsonEgg\bot.py", line 27, in on_message
    data = loads(file.read())
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Imgur link to the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHCoa.jpg

Comment: Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: @JohnGordon K, I think I added the traceback error.

Comment: Your EggData.json file is empty.

Comment: I checked, and it has stuff in it. @Aplet123

Comment: The error message says pretty clearly that it's empty.  Perhaps you have more than one `EggData.json` file, and you're looking at the wrong one?  (Remember that your code does a chdir to `Directory`)

Comment: Check the value that `appendUserID` has after you do `usernameList.append(addUsersID)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, slight error here. When using dictionaries (AKA json), you simply cannot use the .append() as dictionaries do not work that way. Dicttionaries (json) follow a key value pairing system, so you need to assign a key and value as show below...

Proper usage is:

```
my_dict["myvalue"]="another value"
#So in your case: 
usernameList[addUsersID]=#do something here...
```

The error you received is probably because there was nothing in the json/ the format has messed up. Also I noticed that you are making a discord bot. Consider joining the discord.py server, you can receive further support there. I found it useful a while back when I first started making bots. Hope the above helps!

Comment: What am I supposed to do with the `#do something here...`?
Sorry, This is one of my first times using json.

Comment: Nevermind, I found a different solution, which I am going to add, but your answer also worked as well, so I am going to add it to mark it as the answer.

Comment: @EchoTheAlpha Sorry about late response, I was busy recently. For that part, you need to assign that dictionary key with a value, so whatever information about that user perhaps as another dictionary or list would be suitable.

Comment: Its ok, I was able to figure it out a while ago. Thanks for the help!